# Prove this solution is genuine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I cannot prove that the solution to :$$y'=-\frac{x\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

is:

$$y=\sqrt{x^2-2C\sqrt{-x^2+1}-C^2},\:y=-\sqrt{x^2-2C\sqrt{-x^2+1}-C^2}$$

By substituting the solution(s) back into the original equation. I have taken derivative and attempted to equate LHS with RHS but I just can't simplify enough to obviously justify the solution(s) $$\frac{x\left(C+\sqrt{-x^2+1}\right)}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}\sqrt{x^2-2C\sqrt{-x^2+1}-C^2}}$$

Comment: You can separate  the variables and integrate.

Comment: @Tavish That is how he got the solutions in the first place...He just need to verify.

Comment: @PierreCarre Oh, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square the solution:
$$y^2 = x^2-2C\sqrt{1-x^2}-C^2$$

Taking the derivative:
$$2yy'= 2x+2C\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

So
$$yy' = x + C\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{x\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Assuming $x$ is not $0$, then
$$\sqrt{1-x^2} + C=\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Squaring both sides:
$$1-x^2+2C\sqrt{1-x^2}+C^2=1-y^2$$

Then,
$$y^2=x^2-2C\sqrt{1-x^2}-C^2$$

QED

================

The solution to this ODE is by first noticing it is separable. Then you arrive at the equation:
$$-\sqrt{1-y^2}=\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$

This gives you the solution:
$$y^2 = x^2-2C\sqrt{1-x^2}-C^2$$